# colect/get all data from many to many relation with Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many

I try to build app with spring and hibernate, buat i have problem with many to many relation table. i sucsesful add to database, but i got a problem with colect the data.
there is user and role tabel with this relation.
i try to get all user role data, example if user have 2 role(Role_user and Role_admin), i want to colect all role from spesific user. but put the script, i se the log hibernate sucses to collect data, but after that the hibernate also delete the user role data. it weird , i try to find the bug because i dont put delete method.

here my scipt

user.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String userName;

private String email;

private String password;

private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable
private List<Role> roles;
/**
@OneToOne
private Employee employee;
**/
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

/**
 * @return the enabled
 */
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

/**
 * @param enabled the enabled to set
 */
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}




}
```

Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Role {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
private List<User> users;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}


}
```

UserController.java

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value="user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("userlist", this.userService.findAll());

    return "user";
}

    //for add and edit
    @RequestMapping(value= "/addAndEditUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addAndEditUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        if(user.getId() == 0){
            //new employee status, call save
            this.userService.save(user);
        }else{
            this.userService.update(user);
        }


        return "redirect:/user";

    }

    //For add 
    @RequestMapping(value= "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        //new employee status, call save
        this.userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:/user";

    }

    //for edit
    @RequestMapping(value= "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){

        //existing Employee status, call update function from service

        userService.update(user);
        return "redirect:/user";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/removeUser/{id}")
    public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){

        this.userService.delete(id);
        return "redirect:/user";
    }

    //for call edit in list
    @RequestMapping("/editUser/{id}")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){

        model.addAttribute("religionlist", this.userService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.findById(id));
        return "formUser";
    }
     @RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
     public String detail(Model model, @PathVariable int id){
         model.addAttribute("users", userService.findOneWithRole(id));

         return "user-detail";
     }

 }
```

userSericeImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{
@Autowired
private UserDao userDao;



@Transactional
public User findById(int id) {
    return userDao.findById(id);
}

@Transactional
public List<User> findAll() {
    return userDao.findAll();
}

@Transactional
public void save(User user) {
    user.setEnabled(true);


    userDao.save(user);

}

@Transactional
public void update(User user) {
    userDao.update(user);

}

@Transactional
public void delete(int id) {
    userDao.delete(id);

}

@Transactional
public User findOne(int id) {

    return userDao.findOne(id);
}

@Transactional
public User findOneWithRole(int id) {

    return userDao.findOneWithRole(id);
}

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

private static final Logger logger =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private RoleDao roleDao;

public User findById(int id) {

    return (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> findAll() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<User> userList = session.createQuery("from User").list();
    return userList;
}


public void save(User user) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    //roles.add(roleDao.findById(2));


    roles.add(roleDao.findByName("ROLE_USER"));
    user.setRoles(roles);

    session.persist(user);
}


public void update(User user) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(user);
    logger.info("Employee Status updated successfully, departement  Details="+user);
}


public void delete(int id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(findById(id));

}

public User findOne(int id) {

    return (User)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(User.class, id);
}


public User findOneWithRole(int id) {
    User user = findById(id);
    List<Role> roles =  roleDao.findByUser(id);
    user.setRoles(roles);
    return user;
}

}
```

RoleDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
public class RoleDaoImpl implements RoleDao{
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RoleDaoImpl.class);

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public Role findById(int id) {

    return (Role)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Role.class, id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Role> findAll() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Role> roleList = session.createQuery("from Role").list();
    return roleList;
}


public void save(Role role) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(role);
}


public void update(Role role) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(role);
    logger.info("Employee Status updated successfully, departement Details="+role);
}


public void delete(int id) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(findById(id));

}


public Role findByName(String name) {

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Role where name=:name");
    query.setParameter("name", name);
    Role role = (Role)query.uniqueResult();
    return role;
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Role> findByUser(int id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Role> roles = session.createQuery("from Role where id=:id").setString("id", "%" + id + "%").list();

    return roles;
}


}
```

User-detail.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>


<h1>${users.userName}</h1>
<br>
User Role
<c:forEach items="${users.roles}" var="role">
<h1>${role.name}</h1>

</c:forEach>
```

Log app when i see the user detail:

```
10:34:32,801 DEBUG AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource:108 - Adding    transactional method 'UserServiceImpl.findOneWithRole' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
Hibernate: 
 select
    user0_.id as id6_0_,
    user0_.email as email6_0_,
    user0_.enabled as enabled6_0_,
    user0_.password as password6_0_,
    user0_.userName as userName6_0_ 
 from
    User user0_ 
 where
    user0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
 select
    role0_.id as id5_,
    role0_.name as name5_ 
 from
    Role role0_ 
 where
    role0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
 delete 
 from
    User_Role 
 where
    users_id=?
```

how can the delete method call?
how i can fix this?
i want to list all role from spesific user.

thanks in advance :)
if you don't mind teach me how to update and delete (many to many) also...:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, I see that you call userService.findOneWithRole(id) to get the user details, like below:

```
 @RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
 public String detail(Model model, @PathVariable int id){
     model.addAttribute("users", userService.findOneWithRole(id));

     return "user-detail";
 }
```

Track back to your findOneWithRole(int id) method in your UserDaoImpl class, you will see that you assign roles to your user which is not necessary, and also cause the DELETE to happen. You can try removing this and see if it works.

```
public User findOneWithRole(int id) {
    User user = findById(id);
    List<Role> roles =  roleDao.findByUser(id);
    user.setRoles(roles); // <-- THIS LINE
    return user;
}
```

Comment: yeah it's works after i add fetch = FetchType.EAGER in entity, but how user still get the role data?

user.setRoles(roles);  <--- didn't it used to store roles data to user?

Comment: You have the two tables mapped and you ask it to eagerly fetch all data. If you use LAZY load and are using Spring mvc/webflow you may need to add the OpenInView something filter to keep the session in your view.

Comment: i don't get it,
sorry i'm newbie....
can you explain more detail or give me some reference ebook or link to understand this?
thanks before

Comment: There are lots of resources available on the Internet, here is one I found very helpful http://uaihebert.com/jpa-manytomany-unidirectional-and-bidirectional/